# Possible to use Firebase App indexing for PWA stickers?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-app-indexing, progressive-web-apps

I am looking to build a digital sticker purchase app and use Firebase App indexing to make those stickers available in Gboard (as per https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/09/create-stickers-for-gboard-on-google.html).

However, rather than build a native Android app it would be my preference to build a PWA where users can purchase the stickers.

However, as far as I can tell there is no documentation on using Firebase App Indexing with PWA's.

Can anyone offer any definitive insight into whether this is possible or even if it is on the roadmap for Firebase / PWA?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Firebase App Indexing supports indexing content in native Android and iOS apps. It does not support web applications at the moment.

To index the content of your web app, consider one of the many web indexing tools out there, such as [Google's custom search engine](https://cse.google.com/cse/).